# Python; finding the factors of a number code using a dictionary. Why doesn't this work?

Tags: python, list, dictionary, factors

In this function to get the factors of numbers between (start, end), 
I thought the best approach would be to define a dictionary of these numbers, and then append the factors a list assigned to that number.
Is there anything wrong with this approach? If not, then why doesn't this work --> ?

```
def factors(start, end):

   factors = {}

   for number in range(start, end + 1):
      for i in range(2, number+1):
         if number % i == 0:
            factors[number] = []
            factors[number].append(i)
```

In the code, the parameters are the start and end values, and factors is the dictionary in which the numbers and their respective factors are stored.

The idea is to loop through the numbers in the range, then for each one loop through all its possible factors, determine which are indeed factors and add these to the dictionary.

Does this make sense?

Thank you

Comment: By the way, it's a little bit unusual to name your return dictionary the same as your function. In this case it's not a problem, but if for whatever reason you wanted to turn this into a recursive function, it wouldn't work. In general I'd recommend not shadowing your function names like this.

Comment: Agreed;; thanks for the feedback!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are at least two problems with your approach:

1. You're setting `factors[number] = []` every time you find a factor. That means every time you find a factor, you erase the previously found one. Since on the last iteration of the loop, `i` will equal `number`, and `number % number == 0`, your list of factors will always contain only `number` itself.
2. You're not returning anything from your function.

The minimal change I see to make your function work is to move `factors[number] = []` outside the inner loop, and to return the `factors` dictionary when you're done:

```
def factors(start, end):

    factors = {}

    for number in range(start, end + 1):
        factors[number] = []
        for i in range(2, number+1):
            if number % i == 0:
                factors[number].append(i)
    return factors
```

Comment: Wow! Thank you so much!

Comment: Is it necessary to include the factors[number] = [ ] bit? Or can this be left out?

Comment: I suggest you try it and find out :)

Comment: Thank you:: how did you get to this point where you can look at code and know what's wrong with it?

Comment: I've been programming for almost 40 years, and professionally with Python for almost half of that :)

Answer (score 0):

I could not completely get the problem. Its better to provide an example and expected result. Here is what I think works.

```
def factors(start, end):

    factors = {}

    for number in range(start, end+1):
        factors[number] = []
        for i in range(2, number+1):
            if number % i == 0:
                factors[number].append(i)
    return factors

print(factors(10,20))
```

Is that what you are looking for?

Comment: This has the same problem as the original: the returned `factors` dictionary only contains the given numbers themselves: `{10: 10, 11: 11, 12: 12, 13: 13, 14: 14, 15: 15, 16: 16, 17: 17, 18: 18, 19: 19, 20: 20}`. I'd suggest trying your code before to make sure it makes sense before posting.

Comment: And now your code is identical to what I posted. Convergent evolution :)

Comment: Sorry I could not get the exact problem. Just corrected mine. Sorry about that

Comment: It's fine - it really is the simplest way to fix it.